# Improper output of codes (making random word) put in 'Word Finding' game

Tags: python, kivy

I am making game of word finding with help of 'python' and 'kivy'.
I made PlotName(LabelObj,word,direction=0,plot=-1) function.
This function make word in 10x10 word grid at random place.

Ex.PlotName(LabelObg,'ORANGE',1) -LabelObg is label object of kivy for 10x10 grid plots. 
direction is 0=horizontal , 1=vertical , 2=crossup , 3=crossdown word making.

When ABC and AXY like word tried to put in same plots, This function first check it and correct it.

But sometimes i got Problems Like shown below picture.

[image]

New Word Overwrite Previous Word.

I don't know why i am getting this problem.(I thinks its problem of nested loops.)

Here My Full Game.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1m0W0KDsvmKcTg68LHfVsFS4P_m2d-jn_

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
import random

def PlotName(LabelObj,word,direction=0,plot=-1):
    word = word
    direction = direction  # 0=horizontal , 1=vertical , 2=crossup , 3=crossdown
    if(plot!=-1):Rand=plot
    else:Rand = random.randint(0 ,99)
    newRand=Rand

#Checking of previous occupied places

    while (True and WordBox.Occupied_plots!=[]):
        bool=True
        if (direction == 0):

            while True:
                if ((10 - int(str(Rand / 10).split('.')[1])) >= len(word)):
                    for i in word:
                        if (LabelObj[Rand].text!=i and LabelObj[Rand].text!='%'):
                            bool = False
                        Rand += 1
                    break

                elif ((10 - int(str((99 - Rand) / 10).split('.')[1])) >= len(word)):
                    for i in word:
                        if (LabelObj[Rand].text!=i and LabelObj[Rand].text!='%'):
                            bool = False
                        Rand -= 1
                    break

                Rand = random.randint(0 ,99)

        if (direction == 1):

            while True:
                if ((10 - int(Rand / 10)) >= len(word)):
                    for i in word:
                        if (LabelObj[Rand].text!=i and LabelObj[Rand].text!='%'):
                            bool = False
                        Rand += 10
                    break

                elif ((10 - int((99 - Rand) / 10)) >= len(word)):
                    for i in word:
                        if (LabelObj[Rand].text!=i and LabelObj[Rand].text!='%'):
                            bool = False
                        Rand -= 10
                    break

                Rand = random.randint(0, 99)

        if (direction == 2):

            while True:
                if ((10 - int(Rand / 10)) >= len(word)) and ((10 - int(str(Rand / 10).split('.')[1])) >= len(word)):
                    for i in word:
                        if (LabelObj[Rand].text!=i and LabelObj[Rand].text!='%'):
                            bool = False
                        Rand += 10
                        Rand += 1
                    break

                elif ((10 - int((99 - Rand) / 10)) >= len(word)) and (
                        (10 - int(str((99 - Rand) / 10).split('.')[1])) >= len(word)):
                    for i in word:
                        if (LabelObj[Rand].text!=i and LabelObj[Rand].text!='%'):
                            bool = False
                        Rand -= 10
                        Rand -= 1
                    break

                Rand = random.randint(0, 99)

        if (direction == 3):

            while True:
                if ((int(Rand / 10)) >= len(word)) and ((10 - int(str(Rand / 10).split('.')[1])) >= len(word)):
                    for i in word:
                        if (LabelObj[Rand].text!=i and LabelObj[Rand].text!='%'):
                            bool = False
                        Rand -= 10
                        Rand += 1
                    break

                elif ((int((99 - Rand) / 10)) >= len(word)) and (
                        (10 - int(str((99 - Rand) / 10).split('.')[1])) >= len(word)):
                    for i in word:
                        if (LabelObj[Rand].text!=i and LabelObj[Rand].text!='%'):
                            bool = False
                        Rand += 10
                        Rand -= 1
                    break

                Rand = random.randint(0, 99)

        if(bool):
            break
        else:
            Rand = random.randint(0 ,99)
            newRand=Rand

#After Checking -- Put Word --

    Rand=newRand
    if (direction == 0):

        while True:
            if ((10 - int(str(Rand / 10).split('.')[1])) >= len(word)):
                for i in word:
                    LabelObj[Rand].text = i
                    LabelObj[Rand].color = (1, 0, 0, 1)
                    WordBox.Occupied_plots.append(Rand)
                    Rand += 1
                break

            elif ((10 - int(str((99 - Rand) / 10).split('.')[1])) >= len(word)):
                for i in word:
                    LabelObj[Rand].text = i
                    LabelObj[Rand].color = (1, 0, 0, 1)
                    WordBox.Occupied_plots.append(Rand)
                    Rand -= 1
                break

            Rand = random.randint(0 ,99)

    if (direction == 1):


        while True:
            if ((10 - int(Rand / 10)) >= len(word)):
                for i in word:
                    LabelObj[Rand].text = i
                    LabelObj[Rand].color = (1, 0, 0, 1)
                    WordBox.Occupied_plots.append(Rand)
                    Rand += 10
                break

            elif ((10 - int((99 - Rand) / 10)) >= len(word)):
                for i in word:
                    LabelObj[Rand].text = i
                    LabelObj[Rand].color = (1, 0, 0, 1)
                    WordBox.Occupied_plots.append(Rand)
                    Rand -= 10
                break

            Rand = random.randint(0 ,99)


    if (direction == 2):

        while True:
            if ((10 - int(Rand / 10)) >= len(word)) and ((10 - int(str(Rand / 10).split('.')[1])) >= len(word)):
                for i in word:
                    LabelObj[Rand].text = i
                    LabelObj[Rand].color = (1, 0, 0, 1)
                    WordBox.Occupied_plots.append(Rand)
                    Rand += 10
                    Rand += 1
                break

            elif ((10 - int((99 - Rand) / 10)) >= len(word)) and (
                    (10 - int(str((99 - Rand) / 10).split('.')[1])) >= len(word)):
                for i in word:
                    LabelObj[Rand].text = i
                    LabelObj[Rand].color = (1, 0, 0, 1)
                    WordBox.Occupied_plots.append(Rand)
                    Rand -= 10
                    Rand -= 1
                break

            Rand = random.randint(0 ,99)

    if (direction == 3):

        while True:
            if ((int(Rand / 10)) >= len(word)) and ((10 - int(str(Rand / 10).split('.')[1])) >= len(word)):
                for i in word:
                    LabelObj[Rand].text = i
                    LabelObj[Rand].color = (1, 0, 0, 1)
                    WordBox.Occupied_plots.append(Rand)
                    Rand -= 10
                    Rand += 1
                break

            elif ((int((99 - Rand) / 10)) >= len(word)) and (
                    (10 - int(str((99 - Rand) / 10).split('.')[1])) >= len(word)):
                for i in word:
                    LabelObj[Rand].text = i
                    LabelObj[Rand].color = (1, 0, 0, 1)
                    WordBox.Occupied_plots.append(Rand)
                    Rand += 10
                    Rand -= 1
                break

            Rand = random.randint(0 ,99)

class MainScreen(Screen):
    def switch(self,direction,screen):
        self.manager.current=screen

class GameScreen(Screen):
    pass

class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class RootWid(FloatLayout):
    player='player'
    def inpChange1(self,x):
        if(x.text=='player'):
            x.text=''
        elif(x.text==''):
            x.text='player'

    def ok_click(self):
        self.parent.switch('left','game_scr')
        RootWid.player=self.ids['inp1']

class RootWid2(FloatLayout):
    pass

class WordBox(FloatLayout):
    Myself=object
    Occupied_plots=[]

    def myself(self):
        WordBox.Myself=self
        original_Dictionary = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R',
                               'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
        LabelObj=[]
        y=0
        x=0
        for i in range(100):
            if(x>0.99):
                x=0
                y+=0.1

            Latter=random.randint(0,25)
            labelobj=Label(text='%',pos_hint={'x':x,'y':y},size_hint=(0.1,0.1))
            x+=0.1

            self.add_widget(labelobj)
            LabelObj.append(labelobj)

        PlotName(LabelObj,'BANANA',0,13)
        PlotName(LabelObj,'ORANGE',3,17)

        return ''

class NameBox(FloatLayout):
    names=['','','','','','','','','','']
    Myself=object

    def myself(self):
        NameBox.Myself=self
        return ''

    @staticmethod
    def get_names():
        for i in range(10):
            NameBox.names[i]=NameBox.Myself.ids['lbl_'+str(i+1)].text
        return NameBox.names
    @staticmethod
    def set_names(name,index=1):
        NameBox.Myself.ids['lbl_'+str(index)].text=name

class MyCanvas(FloatLayout):
    pass

class Credit(FloatLayout):
    pass

class Mygame(App):

    def build(self):
        return Manager()

Mygame().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried hours.
I go in each if-else-loop codes.
Finally Found My Answer.

I have to assign value of Rand to newRand everytime when Rand take new value from random.randint(0,99).

e.g.

```
            Rand = random.randint(0 ,99)
            newRand=Rand
```

Thank you for give your time to read my QnA. :)